# ejemplo en campo de formulario de registro django

Tags: django, formularios

como puedo colocar texto de ejemplo dentro de un campo de un formulario de registro django.

algo así  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si solo buscas insertar un texto estático dentro del input que le de al usuario una idea de la estructura que un email debe tener basta con usar el atributo placeholder que acepta una cadena de texto, misma que colocará en un texto de tono suave en dicho input

```html
<input type="email" placeholder="ej: gerencia@miempresa.com" required>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si deseas mostrar información para guiar al usuario, puedes hacerlo desde el modelo de esta manera, aunque ten en cuenta que no se muestra dentro el input, sino debajo

```
class Estudiante(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField('Nombre', max_length=15, help_text="Escriba su nombre")
```

Answer (score 3):

Usando los formularios que te proporciona Django, estos son definidos en el fichero forms.py (por defecto, ojo lo puedes cambiarle el nombre) sería algo como esto más o menos:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= TUMODELO
        fields = ['email']

        widgets = {
            'comentario': forms.EmailInput(
                 attrs={'class': 'form-control','required': 'required', 'placeholder': 'ej: mario.palma@mipega.cl'})
        }
```

TUMODELO es tu modelo de Registro, el atributo `fields` define los campos del modelo que quieres incluir en tu formulario y en `widgets` es donde le das forma al input que luego se renderiza en la plantilla